# Is there any way to show an .DWG file in the browser using asp.net

Tags: c#, draw

I am trying to show an AutoCAD .DWG file in my web form.
I found this code in https://cadsofttools.com/products/cad-net/

...

```
using CADImport;
using CADImport.DWG;
using CADImport.DXF;
using CADImport.RasterImage;
...
private void Read_DWG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DWGImage class is used only for reading DWG. To read other formatsuse the corresponding classes. 
    //E.g. for DXF: CADImage class, for PLT/HPGL: HPGLImage class.
        DWGImage vDrawing = new DWGImage();
        vDrawing.LoadFromFile(@"..\..\..\Files\Gasket.dwg");
        vDrawing.Draw(Image1.CreateGraphics(), new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)vDrawing.AbsWidth,
            (float)vDrawing.AbsHeight)); // zooming and panning of the drawing are implemented
            //in the demo Viewer via a special viewing control class CADPictureBox
}
```

I have already installed the required libraries and reference them in my web project. I have a problem with  " Image1.CreateGraphics() " I don't know what is Image1!

Answer (score 0):

`Image1` is assuming a `Windows Forms` Image control. You are not going to be able to display the image in asp.net using that code.

You have more than one issue here when trying to display with asp.net. Also I'm not familiar with `DWGImage` or the related library. But you can try this:

```
using(var image = new Bitmap())
{
  DWGImage vDrawing = new DWGImage();
  vDrawing.LoadFromFile(@"..\..\..\Files\Gasket.dwg");
  vDrawing.Draw(image, new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)vDrawing.AbsWidth,
            (float)vDrawing.AbsHeight)); 
}
```

As a start, if that does not blow up and `image` does contain data (use your debugger to find out), then you can use a `HttpHandler` (.ashx) to show your image. Confirm that code above works then I can show you the HttpHandler code.

Comment: unfortunately, I tried image control and it did not work. 
 the main problem is in Draw function it should contain ( Graphics object, Rectangle object ), the problem is in Graphics object. 
I tried to declare a new graphics object as follows, but it did not work.
Graphics g;  
g = this.CreateGraphics();

Comment: Those are Windows Forms constructs, you wont get anywhere trying them.